# cant insert email through POST method

Tags: php, html, post

I have code that gets data from the form through a `POST` method, but there seems to be some kind of problem here.

Below are the code snippets. Help me if you can find any problem with it.

**Getting error:**

```
some mandatory fields are empty and it is for the field email_address.
Undefined index: email_address in C:\wamp\www\test\employeee_insert.php
```

**My form data:**

```
<tr>
   <td>email address:</td>
   <td><input type="email" name="email_address"></td>
</tr>
```

**My php file data:**

```
if (empty($_POST["type"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["branch"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["name"]) OR      
    empty($_POST["address_1"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["state"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["city"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["pincode"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["mobile"]) OR 
    empty($_POST["email_address"]) OR  
    empty($_POST["password"])) 
{ 
    echo "some mendetory field(s) is/are empty. Please fill in the necessary details. ";
    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

**Insert code**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO     employee_basic_info(employee_name,employee_type,branch,address_1,address_2,state,city,pincode,landline,mobile,email_address,password)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['type']."','".$_POST['branch']."','".$_POST['address_1']."', '".$_POST['address_2']."','".$_POST['state']."','".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['pincode']."','".$_POST['landline']."','".$_POST['mobile']."','".$_POST['email_address']."','".$_POST['password']."')";
```

Comment: Yet, you only close a mysqli connection - where is your insert? where is your html-form?

Comment: What kind of problem does there seem to be? What's the expected behaviour? What's the actual behaviour?

Comment: its working all fine. i dont see any need to show all those codes here. if i remove this condition than all the data is being inserted except email_address.

Comment: I'm assuming you are seeing the mandatory field empty error? If so this will be because PHP isn't receiving one of the fields. Check your input names on your HTML form, or use the print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @Oswald its jst dat email_address field in the form seems to be empty. its not getting any value from the form.

Comment: @rybo111 YES. its the email_address field.

Comment: How much debugging have you done on this mate?

Comment: show the line that how you getting email for inserting...

Comment: @scrowler everything is working all fine.. jst this email_address is annoying. no need for debugging yet. been trying to solve this error, bt nt successfully!

Comment: @Dev thats the form data... the first code snippet

Comment: Yes need for debugging! remove all your other variables and change things until you get it to work. This is not SO worthy.

Comment: @user3243970 dear, this is your validation, but show me your insert query, which you are using for inserting...

Comment: @Dev added into the main question above.

Comment: So much edit clutter! When you edit a post, kindly fix **all** problems with it at once, including spelling, grammar and code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong type in email address field. if you get the text type then it should be submit all data either if you does not want to change the type of email address then you enter valid email address so your prob can be solved

email address:

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

```
if (empty($_POST["type"])||
    empty($_POST["branch"])|| 
    empty($_POST["name"]) ||      
    empty($_POST["address_1"])|| 
    empty($_POST["state"])||
    empty($_POST["city"]) || 
    empty($_POST["pincode"])||
    empty($_POST["mobile"]) || 
    empty($_POST["email_address"])||  
    empty($_POST["password"])) 
{ 
echo "some mendetory field(s) is/are empty. Please fill in the necessary details. ";
//mysqli_close($con); 
}
else
{
    echo $ins='insert into tbl_name(`type`,`branch`,`name`,`address_1`,`state`,`city`,`pincode`,`mobile`,`email_address`,`password`)values("'.$_POST["type"].'","'.$_POST["branch"].'","'.$_POST["name"].'","'.$_POST["address_1"].'","'.$_POST["state"].'","'.$_POST["city"].'","'.$_POST["pincode"].'","'.$_POST["mobile"].'","'.$_POST["email_address"].'","'.$_POST["type"].'")';
    mysql_query($ins);
}
```

}